2-electron integral, J and K
I'm studying Hartree-Fock. Two electron integral is expressed as :

and the Hartree-Fock energy for is the sum of 1-electron integral + J - K.

My question is, J and K seems a special case of 2-electron integral. But why only J and K are included in the total energy equation?
Thank you.

The question seems vague. The J-type integral accounts for all Coulomb repulsion in the system while the K-type integral tries to account for the exchange of energy. I would look into the Roothan Hall equations. From memory, the J and K-type integrals should cover all possible two-electron integrals in the system. If you have access, Peter Atkins' Molecular Quantum Mechanics has some good explanations.
